# Postgres is ignoring a timestamp index, why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following tables:

```
users (id, network_id)
networks (id)
private_messages (id, sender_id, receiver_id, created_at)
```

I have indexes on users.network_id, and all 3 columns in private messages however the query is skipping the indexes and taking a very long time to run. Any ideas what is wrong in the query that is causing the index to be skipped?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "networks" 
WHERE (
          networks.created_at BETWEEN ((timestamp '2013-01-01')) AND (( (timestamp '2013-01-31') + interval '-1 second'))
          AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM private_messages INNER JOIN users ON private_messages.receiver_id = users.id WHERE users.network_id = networks.id AND (private_messages.created_at BETWEEN ((timestamp '2013-03-01')) AND (( (timestamp '2013-03-31') + interval '-1 second'))) ) > 0)
```

Result:

```
Aggregate  (cost=722675247.10..722675247.11 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=519916.108..519916.108 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on networks  (cost=0.00..722675245.34 rows=703 width=0) (actual time=2576.205..519916.044 rows=78 loops=1)
        Filter: ((created_at >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2013-01-30 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((SubPlan 1) > 0))
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=50671.34..50671.35 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=240.359..240.359 rows=1 loops=2163)
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=10333.69..50671.27 rows=28 width=0) (actual time=233.997..240.340 rows=13 loops=2163)
                      Hash Cond: (private_messages.receiver_id = users.id)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on private_messages  (cost=10127.11..48675.15 rows=477136 width=4) (actual time=56.599..232.855 rows=473686 loops=1809)
                            Recheck Cond: ((created_at >= '2013-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2013-03-30 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_private_messages_on_created_at  (cost=0.00..10007.83 rows=477136 width=0) (actual time=54.551..54.551 rows=473686 loops=1809)
                                  Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2013-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2013-03-30 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                      ->  Hash  (cost=205.87..205.87 rows=57 width=4) (actual time=0.218..0.218 rows=2 loops=2163)
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 0kB
                            ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_network_id on users  (cost=0.00..205.87 rows=57 width=4) (actual time=0.154..0.215 rows=2 loops=2163)
                                  Index Cond: (network_id = networks.id)
Total runtime: 519916.183 ms
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your selectivity on a month-wide time span?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs not sure I follow your question? I use a between in the query, the query is in the question above. Is that what you need?

Comment: if your range encompasses 20% of your records (or any percentage over around 5%) the rdbms will not try to use the index, as it will usually be more efficient to perform a table scan.  If that index will match on less than 5% of the records, the chances of that index being used is much higher.  You can check this by making the range much narrower and see if the index starts getting used.

Comment: The explain output shows that it does use `index_private_messages_on_created_at`. What other index do you think is skipped?

Comment: @DanielVérité just the index_private_messages_on_created_at which is the problem

Comment: @tim I'm having troubled getting that to work, would you mind posting an answer with the updated query?

Comment: To improve your query, maybe you should first get rid of this clause:  (SELECT count(*)...)>0 in favor of a real relational join, or at least an `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: I'm going to change my advice. Can you test for existence instead of counting?

Comment: @Tim if you're able to post an answer with an update I cant test it out quickly

Comment: What happens if you do this: `select * from networks N
inner join users U on U.network_id = N.id and N.created_at between (T1 and t2)
inner join private_messages PM on PM.receiver_id = U.id and PM.create_at between (t1 and t2)`  substituting your timestamps of course for t1 and t2.

Comment: @tim that results in: select * 
from networks N inner join users U on U.network_id = N.id and N.created_at between ((timestamp '2013-03-01 23:59:59') and (timestamp '2013-03-31 23:59:59')) inner join private_messages PM on PM.receiver_id = U.id and PM.create_at between (timestamp '2013-03-01 23:59:59') and (timestamp '2013-03-31 23:59:59')   --- this is resulting in a syntax error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "inner"
LINE 2: ...23:59:59') and (timestamp '2013-03-31 23:59:59')) inner join...
                                                             ^

Comment: What version of PG are you on?

Comment: @JustBob: Missed the tag 9.1?

Comment: yes 9.1 is our version

Answer (score 2):

Let's try something different. I am only suggesting this as an "answer" because of its length and you cannot format a comment. Let's approach the query modularly as a series of subsets that need to get intersected. Let's see how long it takes each of these to execute (please report). Substitute your timestamps for t1 and t2. Note how each query builds upon the prior one, making the prior one an "inline view".

EDIT: also, please confirm the columns in the Networks table.

## 1

```
 select PM.receiver_id from private_messages PM
 where PM.create_at between (t1 and t2)
```

## 2

```
 select U.id, U.network_id from users U
 join
 (
   select PM.receiver_id from private_messages PM 
   where PM.create_at between (t1 and t2)
 ) as FOO
 on U.id = FOO.receiver_id
```

## 3

```
select N.* from networks N
join
(
select U.id, U.network_id from users U
 join
 (
   select PM.receiver_id from private_messages PM 
   where PM.create_at between (t1 and t2)
 ) as FOO
 on U.id = FOO.receiver_id
) as BAR
on N.id = BAR.network_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you want an index on `network.created_at`, even though right now with over 10% of the table matching the `WHERE`, it probably won't be used.

Next, I expect you will get better speed if you try to get as much logic as possible into one query, instead of splitting some into a subquery. I believe the plan is indicating iterating over each value of `network.id` that matches; usually an all-at-once join works better.

I think the code below is logically equivalent. If not, close.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
 (SELECT users.network_id FROM "networks"
  JOIN users 
  ON users.network_id = networks.id
  JOIN private_messages
  ON private_messages.receiver_id = users.id
   AND (private_messages.created_at 
    BETWEEN ((timestamp '2013-03-01')) 
         AND (( (timestamp '2013-03-31') + interval '-1 second')))
  WHERE 
   networks.created_at 
    BETWEEN ((timestamp '2013-01-01')) 
     AND (( (timestamp '2013-01-31') + interval '-1 second'))
  GROUP BY users.network_id)
     AS main_subquery  
;
```

My experience is that you will get the same query plan if you move the `networks.created_at` into the `ON` clause for the `users-networks` join. I don't think your issue is timestamps; it's the structure of the query. You may also get a better (or worse) plan by replacing the `GROUP BY` in the subquery with `SELECT DISTINCT users.network_id`.